# How to add group column name of our choice

Tags: grouping, ag-grid

I am grouping elements in ag grid table.
The default column name is Group.

[image]

Is it possible / how to add a name of our choice for the Group column
(different than column names we have in our table)?
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid/grouping/

Answer (score 3):

You can change the `headerName` property of the Auto Group Column by providing a `headerName` property in the `autoGroupColumnDef`:

```
gridOptions: {
    autoGroupColumnDef: {
        headerName:'Athletes'
    }
}
```

You can read more about this in the documentation: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid/grouping/#configuring-the-auto-group-column